# Automorphism group of $\mathbb Z_2^3$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, automorphism-group

I am trying to find $\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2^3)$ and express it in terms of familiar groups and the direct and/or semi direct product.

Here's what I have so far: I know that the set of generators $A:=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ of $\mathbb Z_2^3$ must be mapped onto another set of $3$ generators by an arbitrary automorphism $\varphi$. I have calculated combinatorially that $\mathbb Z_2^n$ has $2^n-1$ sets of $n$ generators, and since each automorphism maps $A$ onto one of these $n$-element sets in one of $n!$ ways, there are a total of $n!(2^n-1)$ automorphisms of $\mathbb Z_2^n$.

In summary, $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2^n)|=n!(2^n-1)$. So for $n=3$, we can see that $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2^3)|=6\cdot 7=42$.

Is this reasoning all correct? If so, how do I proceed from here to actually find out what the group $\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2^3)$ is?

Comment: This is not yet correct. How are you "calculating combinatorially" that there are $2^n - 1$ sets of $n$ generators?

Comment: @JoshB. Do you think that is wrong, or have I simply not explained it sufficiently?

Comment: Spoilers: You are missing a factor of $4$, but I can't tell where. In total you should have $7*6*4=168$. Also it may be disappointing, or exciting, but this group is not expressible in terms of familiar groups. In fact, it's a simple group.

Comment: It might be easier to reframe this in terms of linear algebra, where your problem becomes finding all the invertable $3$x$3$ matrices over the field of two elements.

Comment: @JoshB. Is there already a notation for that group? I know that some groups of matrices are used frequently in group theory, but I have not familiarized myself with them yet. What kind of simple group is it?

Comment: The sequence $|\mbox{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_2^n)|$ follows the recursive formula $a_n=(2^n-1)2^{n-1}a_{n-1}$. It can be found on https://oeis.org/A002884 and under formula you can see only products, so I assume there is no known closed formula.

Comment: In this case I would refer to it as $GL(3,2)$. Although this particular group is isomorphic to several different things: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group:PSL(3,2)